# How does someone modify someone's memory?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-theory

### How does someone modify someone's memory?

I have read a lot of parts in the books of Harry Potter where someone *modifies* someone's memory.

**Obliviate** - spell to wipe out someone's memory

I already thought of that spell, but I think that casting that spell will wipe the whole memory.

> Tom modified the memory of Morfin and the House-Elf of Hepzibah

```
HP and the Half Blood Prince
```

> Hermione modified her parents' memories that caused them to go to
>   Australia

`HP and the Deathly Hallows`

Correct me if I'm wrong about my thoughts about the ***Obliviate Spell.*** Is there a certain spell that's specialized to modify someone's memory? If there is, how is its procedure? How does a wizard/witch modify someone's memory?

Comment: With great difficulty and skill, evidently.

Comment: yes but I don't really know how they add the memories they want to that person. But maybe Rowling didn't address yet its specific details

Answer (score 2):

There are two spells that govern memory: [*obliviate*](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Memory_Charm), which erases memories, and a [false memory charm](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/False_Memory_Charm), which creates new ones. The incantation and mechanics of the false memory charm are unknown, but they are clearly two distinct spells. JKR addressed the difference between the two in the Bloomsbury Live Chat in 2007:

> **Laura Trego**: Did Hermione really put a memory charm on her parents? She says she did but then about 50 pages later tells Ron she has never done a memory charm.
>
> **J.K. Rowling**: They are two different charms. She has not wiped her parents' memories (as she later does to Dolohov and Rowle); she has bewitched them to make them believe that they are different people.

Comment: Oh now I know. But I really want to know how they put another memory or add it I can't find a specific answer through my research, maybe it is really unknown.

Comment: It is confusing as in the film they use the same spell but it was never intended to be the same.

Comment: @ThruGog yes in the film Hermione used obliviate which was really odd since it is memory wiper.

Comment: @Book Striker - I guess they thought using the same memory-related spell for both would make it easier for the casual fan to just think "Ah, memory spells." Shame it's confusing for us though!

Comment: @ThruGog. It's really confusing. What's weird is they manage to invent spells in the movie instead of using the spells in the book not included in the movie. But this memory charm is really confusing. When I'm not yet reading the books, I thought that Hermione's parents was totally wiped out of memories and out of world!

Comment: I just wondered: how can a 'false memory charm' create a new memory without wiping out the original memory?

Comment: It seems to leave the old memory in tact, and just bury it. Consider Morfin or Hokey, both of whose memories were modified by Voldemort, but had real memories which Dumbledore was able to recover.